# Not Able to Update woocommerce product as featured programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Not able to update featured product

$pro_data['value'][$i]['Website_x0020_Title'],
                 "post_content" =>$pro_data['value'][$i]['Parcel_x0020_Description'],
                 "post_status" => "publish",
                 "post_type" => "product"
              ); 
         
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($product_array);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Cash_x0020_Price'] );
            update_post_meta($post_id, "_manage_stock", "yes");
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_featured', "true");
          
           if($pro_data['value'][$i]['Stock_x0020_Number'] == 0){
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Stock_x0020_Number']);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock' );
          }
          else{
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Stock_x0020_Number']);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
          }
         update_field('down_payment', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Web_Deposit'], $post_id);
         update_field('purchase_price_main', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Website_x0020_Purchase_x0020_Pri'], $post_id);

?>

```html
<?php

            $product_array =  array(
                 "post_title" => $pro_data['value'][$i]['Website_x0020_Title'],
                 "post_content" =>$pro_data['value'][$i]['Parcel_x0020_Description'],
                 "post_status" => "publish",
                 "post_type" => "product"
              ); 
         
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($product_array);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Cash_x0020_Price'] );
            update_post_meta($post_id, "_manage_stock", "yes");
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_featured', "true");
          
           if($pro_data['value'][$i]['Stock_x0020_Number'] == 0){
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Stock_x0020_Number']);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock' );
          }
          else{
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Stock_x0020_Number']);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
          }
         update_field('down_payment', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Web_Deposit'], $post_id);
         update_field('purchase_price_main', $pro_data['value'][$i]['Website_x0020_Purchase_x0020_Pri'], $post_id);

?>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `product_visibility` value. You can try the below code to update it:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'featured', 'product_visibility' );
```

Comment: Not Working this one